# jQuery ajax POST request with application/json

Tags: ajax, jquery

I want to make a POST request to the remote server from jQuery. When I write code like this

```
$.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://mysite:8080/orderService/order/send',
                crossDomain: true,
                data: JSON.stringify(orderSendRequest),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    var value = responseData.someKey;
                },
                error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('POST failed.');
                }
        });
```

Everything is ok, but I want ContextType to be application/json, and when I add this line to the code the request doesn't work and I have the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mysite:8080/orderService/order/send. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

$.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://mysite:8080/orderService/order/send',
                crossDomain: true,
                data: JSON.stringify(orderSendRequest),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    var value = responseData.someKey;
                },
                error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('POST failed.');
                }
        });
```

Comment: did you figure out whats the different between non content type and content type on the server side? I think, it's not necessary adding a content type when you've added the dataType?

Comment: @wkaha contentType is the type of data you send within your call, dataType is the type of data the callback awaits for.

Comment: @Bardo thats right. i thought i'll be added automatically. thats not true

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe json supports crossDomain. Research using jsonp datatype instead.